# How to handle connection errors to SQL Azure DDBB with EF6

Tags: azure, entity-framework-6, azure-sql-database, azure-worker-roles, transient

I have a Worker Role developed with ASP.NET MVC 4 that implements a REST WS in Azure. It uses Entity Framework v6 to connect to a Azure SQL DDBB. Normally it works fine but sometimes I get an exception when tries to writte to the DDBB with this message:

> An error was reported while committing a database transaction but it
>   could not be determined whether the transaction succeeded or failed on
>   the database server

The error seems to be a connection problem between the Aplication Sever and the DDBB. I have implemented the **SQLAzureExcutionStrategy** (explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456835.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) to get connection resiliency but this does not prevent the error as the connection problem seems to happen during the commit so EF don't know if has to retry or not.

There is a solution explained [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=313468)  that suggest to create a "track check table" in order to insert a "track row" in each transaction and if a transient exception happens (as mine) then check if the row exist or not in the table to decide retring or not. But I'm not sure if this approach is valid when using an ORM like EF.

When I do a **DbContext.SaveChanges()** and a connetion problem happens during the transacion. ¿Can I assume that all or nothing is commited? If not, which strategy should I apply? Try to do SaveChanges on each entitiy update?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Regards,
Ivan.

Comment: I finally get a answer from Microsoft. I have not yet tested but looks that will work: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn630221

Answer (score 0):

If you don't start begin transaction by yourself, *SQLAzureExcutionStrategy* supports `DbContext.SaveChanges()` (it doesn't matter how many entites there). Check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn307226#transactions).

Otherwise, If you really really need use *track check table*. What will happen if you get connection error while you are checking ? You need more work to handle this also. You should do this for all transactions. Because you don't know which one will give error. Errors are very rare. So, It's very expensive.

If you can, follow solution between *Do nothing* and *Use the database to reset state*. Show/return meaningful message to user an do nothing. I follow this solution and it's enough for me.

**My Suggestion:** If you don't begin transaction by yourself continue with *SQLAzureExcutionStrategy*. Otherwise try to choose best solution for you with starting to check cheapest one (*Do nothing*).

Comment: Hi Erkan, thanks for your answer and sorry for my late response. I do not use transacion by myself but SQLAzureExcecutionStrategy it is not working in that scenario. The connection error happens during the transaction and EF is not able to know if needs to retry or not. Actually in some cases the exception happens but the commit has been done.  What I have done is upgrade my AzureDDBB from S0 to S20 and now this connection errors are not hapenning.

Comment: Sorry for this update, but @IvanBASART did you solve this issue just by scaling up the database DTU?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to do the Option 3 in the article.  The best way to do that is using stored procedures to write and read the information, following the prescription below:

Option 3 - Manually track the transaction

1. Add a non-tracked table to the database used to track the status of the transactions.
2. Insert a row into the table at the beginning of each transaction.
3. If the connection fails during the commit, check for the presence of the corresponding row in the database. 
   If the row is present, continue normally, as the transaction was committed successfully
   If the row is absent, use an execution strategy to retry the current operation.
4. If the commit is successful, delete the corresponding row to avoid the growth of the table.

The track table should not be exposed.  That’s why we must encapsulate everything in stored procedures.

Thanks,
Mihaela

Comment: Hi Mihaela, thanks for your answer and sorry for my late response. I think (I am not sure thats the reason of my question) that this option is not reliable using EF as a DBContext.SaveChanges() may handle different commits.  What I have done is upgrade my AzureDDBB from S0 to S20 and now this connection errors are not hapenning.